# Docker: cd into directory using regular expressions

Tags: regex, docker, dockerfile

I have to build a Docker image and in the Dockerfile I have move into a directory whose name contains a dynamic id, e.g `myfolder12345`, that can become `myfolder56789` in another build. As I don't know which can be this id everytime I do the build, I have tried to use regular expressions to achieve that.

I've tried with

```
WORKDIR myfolder*
```

but the current directory remains `/`.
How can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

If you know, during the build of the docker image, the name of the folder, use a variable:

```
WORKDIR ${workdir}
```

And set the variable value during the build.

Answer (score 0):

Having a non-deterministic content in a docker image is a bad idea.

You should rename the folder first, then the `WORKDIR` will be easier:

```
# Supposing there is only one folder123 at each build
RUN mv /path/to/folder* /path/to/folder
WORKDIR /path/to/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

how about trying the regex syntax?

```
WORKDIR workdir[\d]+
```

Let me know if that works for you.